# Word or phrase for stuff washed ashore

Tags: single-word-requests

How might I describe washed up stuff in a word or phrase?

Asking for my granddaughter. She knows about "jetsam" but that's for things deliberately jettisoned:

> unwanted material or goods that have been thrown overboard from a ship
>   and washed ashore, especially material that has been discarded to
>   lighten the vessel - [*OD*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/jetsam)

so does not fit in her story.

Neither does "flotsam", which is wreckage, though not deliberately discarded.
And the "flot" says it's floating, not washed up.

> the part of the wreckage of a ship and its cargo found floating on the
>   water. - [*dictionary.com*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/flotsam-jetsam)

Comment: flotsam washes ashore.

Comment: @Lambie Thanks - but see my edit in response.

Comment: [This](https://oceanservice.noaa.gov/facts/flotsam-jetsam.html) contradicts my understanding, which is **flotsam** is stuff finding its way into the sea which floats, and **jetsam** ditto but sinks. The former may be washed ashore, the latter might sink to the sea bed - all subject to tides and currents.

Comment: Flotsam floats on the water ***and then*** washes ashore. I mean you could say many things here: trash, debris, garbage, detritus. Nothing says that flotsam has to sink. But flotsam works for me. Bottles float on water, can't they wash up onto the shore?? The fact flotsam floats and that it may wash ashore does not mean you can't couple it with washing ashore.

Comment: Interesting question that improved my knowledge.

Comment: *In maritime law, flotsam, jetsam, lagan, and derelict are specific kinds of shipwreck. The words have specific nautical meanings, with legal consequences in the law of admiralty and marine salvage.[1] A shipwreck is defined as the remains of a ship that has been wrecked, a destroyed ship at sea, whether it be sunken or floating on the surface of the water.[2]* [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flotsam,_jetsam,_lagan,_and_derelict)

Comment: This is about a story, not maritime law.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Jetsam** has an extended use outside of maritime law and it can be used for anything washed up on the shore.

> In extended use. Something washed up or discarded; refuse, detritus. - *[OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/101177?redirectedFrom=jetsam#eid)*

However, the news articles usually use the phrase **flotsam and jetsam** for the debris washed up on the shore.

> The foul-smelling haul of **flotsam and jetsam** included plastic containers, bin liners stuffed to bursting and even a pile of cattle bones reached 30m inland. - [*telegraph.co.uk*](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2018/01/23/plastic-putrid-refuse-swamp-beach-lebanons-rubbish-crisis-intensifies/)
>
> ---
>
> A recent stroll along a Bay of Islands beach included the ugly sight of plastic bag remnants tangled all through the **tide line flotsam and jetsam**. - [*stuff.co.nz*](https://www.stuff.co.nz/nelson-mail/opinion/100677993/time-to-end-our-apathy-over-plastic-use)

*[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marine_debris)* offers the terms **beach litter** and **tidewrack** in the *marine debris* article:

> Floating oceanic debris tends to accumulate at the center of gyres and on coastlines, frequently washing aground, when it is known as beach litter or tidewrack.

*Tidewrack* is not that common and it is not defined in big dictionaries; but it has this definition in [*Wiktionary*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tidewrack):

> seaweed and similar marine vegetation and rubbish deposited along a shore by a receding tide

The more common term is simply **wrack** but it is mainly used for the biological debris.

> **3.**
>
> **a.** Marine vegetation, seaweed or the like, cast ashore by the waves or growing on the tidal seashore. (Cf. wreck n.<sup>1</sup> 2, varec n. 1) 
>          <sub>Also **cart-wrack, grass-wrack, kelp-wrack, lady-wrack, sea-wrack.**</sub>
>
> **b.** Weeds, rubbish, waste, etc., floating on, or washed down or ashore by, a river, pond, or the like; = wreck n.<sup>1</sup> 2b.
>
> [*OED*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/230476#eid13922690)

[image]
 <sub>Image source: [www.beachapedia.org](http://www.beachapedia.org/images/thumb/8/8a/BeachWrack.JPG/800px-BeachWrack.JPG)</sub>

Another similar term is **wrack line**.

> In the marine sense, the wrack line is the line of debris left on the beach by high tide.  The wrack is usually made up of eel grass, kelp, crustacean shells, feathers, bits of plastic, and all kinds of litter.
>
> <sub>https://theoutershores.com/wrack-line/</sub>